# Changing color of buttons in tkinter which are created using for loop

Tags: python, button, tkinter

So I have created 5 x 5 buttons using for-loop:

```
for i in range(5):
for j in range(5):
    gameButton = Button(boardFrame, bg="khaki1", width=10, height=5, command=colorTheButton)
    gameButton.grid(row=i, column=j, sticky=E)
```

and I have a function called changeColor():

```
def colorTheButton():
    global colorCounter, boardColor
    row = gameButton.grid_info()['row']
    column = gameButton.grid_info()['column']

    if colorCounter % 2 == 0:
        boardColor = "black"
    else:
        boardColor = "white"
    colorCounter += 1

    button = button(boardFrame, bg=boardColor, width=10, height=5)
    button.grid(row=row, column=column)
```

Now the problem is, every time I click any button it'll not change the color of the clicked button instead, it'll change the color of the last created button. What should I do to change the clicked button instead of the last one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you're creating multiple buttons but they're overwritingly assigned to the very same variable, `gameButton` and thus you can *only* refer to the *last* button created, later on, which would be problematic.

You can instead create your buttons like:

```
gameButton = list()
for i in range(5)
    gameButton.append(list())
    for j in range(5)
        gameButton[i].append(Button(boardFrame, bg="khaki1", width=10, height=5, command=colorTheButton))
        gameButton[i][j].grid(row=i, column=j, sticky=E)
```

Secondly you should rather pass the node information to the `colorTheButton` method instead of trying to find which button is pressed later on:

```
gameButton[i].append(Button(boardFrame, bg="khaki1", width=10, height=5, command=lambda row=i, col=j : colorTheButton(row, col))
```

modify `colorTheButton` accordingly:

```
def colorTheButton(row, column):
    global colorCounter, boardColor
    if colorCounter % 2 == 0:
...
```

Note: Last 2 lines of that function keeps creating non-referable button <strike>objects</strike> *widgets* as well.

So better:

```
def colorTheButton(row, column):
    global colorCounter, boardColor
    if colorCounter % 2 == 0:
        boardColor = "black"
    else:
        boardColor = "white"
    colorCounter += 1

    gameButton[row][column]['bg'] = boardColor
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `for` loop, you give each new button the same name, `gameButton`. This means that only the most recent button is saved to the variable, in this case the bottom right button.

When you say `row = gameButton.grid_info()['row']` and `column = gameButton.grid_info()['column']`, this therefore gets only the last buttons position in the grid. This means that only the last button is updated as you have observed.

To fix this, you could implement a list containing the buttons, or implement another way. One such way is this:

```
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        gameButton = Button(boardFrame, bg="khaki1", width=10, height=5,
                            command=lambda i=i, j=j: colorTheButton(i, j))
        gameButton.grid(row=i, column=j, sticky=E)
```

I changed the command to `lambda i=i, j=j: colorTheButton(i, j)`, which passes the actual grid location of the button to `colorTheButton`.

And then `colorTheButton` is as follows:

```
def colorTheButton(row, column):
    global colorCounter, boardColor
    if colorCounter % 2 == 0:
        boardColor = "black"
    else:
        boardColor = "white"
    colorCounter += 1

    button = Button(boardFrame, bg=boardColor, width=10, height=5)
    button.grid(row=row, column=column)
```

Note that I have tried to keep your code as similar as possible; this code stills produces a *new* button each time, overlaying the old one in place. This is not as efficient as modifying the original button, but that is a different question!